# Property 'stripe-pricing-table' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I am following the Stripe documentation for embedding a pricing table at [link](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table#Create), but run into this error: "Property 'stripe-pricing-table' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'".

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default function PricingTable() {
  return (
    <stripe-pricing-table
      pricing-table-id="prctbl_xxxxx"
      publishable-key="pk_test_xxxxx"
    ></stripe-pricing-table>
  );
}
```

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that's more of a Typescript problem, you might have to declare a type for `stripe-pricing-table` along the lines of

```
import * as React from 'react'

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      'stripe-pricing-table': React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how to use this code ?

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil you will need to do the following (I modified the property in the e code):


declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            ['stripe-pricing-table']: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>;
        }
    }
}

Comment: I had to add quotes around the `stripe-pricing-table` key to make this work.

Comment: In addition to the quotes, I also had to add 
`import * as React from 'react'` on top of the file to make it work

Answer (score 10):

A bit late but if you are using React with Typescript, this is how I did it.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const StripePricingTable = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        };
    }, []);

    return React.createElement("stripe-pricing-table", {
        "pricing-table-id": {PRICING TABLE ID GOES HERE},
        "publishable-key": {PUBLISHABLE KEY GOES HERE},
    });
};

export default StripePricingTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the `pricing-table.js` script in the index.html?

```
<script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with this approach to inject the embed code as it is:

```js
function stripeEmbed() {
  return {
    __html: `<script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js"></script>
    <stripe-pricing-table pricing-table-id="prctbl_xxxx"
    publishable-key="pk_test_xxxx">
    </stripe-pricing-table>`
  };
}

export function PricingTable() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={stripeEmbed()} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this with NextJS

```
  const NextStripePricingTable = ({ pricingTableId, publishableKey, clientReferenceId }) => {
    if (!pricingTableId || !publishableKey) return null
    return (
      <>
        <Script async strategy="lazyOnload" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js" />
        <stripe-pricing-table
          pricing-table-id={pricingTableId}
          publishable-key={publishableKey}
          client-reference-id={clientReferenceId}
        />
      </>
    )
  }
```

from https://zenn.dev/hideokamoto/scraps/c588966247b1f9